# Hyperlink too large

Tags: hyperref, eps, includegraphics

I have a hyperlink enclosing an includegraphics.  The hyperlink page dimensions are much much larger than the page dimensions of the enclosed includegraphics.[image: Tiny image, exaggerated link extents]

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx,lmodern,wasysym,paralist}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={2018},
    colorlinks=false,
}
\usepackage[paperheight=148mm,paperwidth=069mm,margin=4mm,top=1.75cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \hyperlink{linkdest}{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.045\textwidth]{mwe1}}}
    \newpage
    \hypertarget{linkdest}{linkdest}\newpage
\end{document}
```

The (mwe=blank) is also pasted here.

How can the hyperlink size be reduced to be tightly around the enclosed graphic?

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: cairo 1.15.6 (http://cairographics.org)
%%CreationDate: Thu Aug 09 11:00:27 2018
%%Pages: 1
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 311 425
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
save
50 dict begin
/q { gsave } bind def
/Q { grestore } bind def
/cm { 6 array astore concat } bind def
/w { setlinewidth } bind def
/J { setlinecap } bind def
/j { setlinejoin } bind def
/M { setmiterlimit } bind def
/d { setdash } bind def
/m { moveto } bind def
/l { lineto } bind def
/c { curveto } bind def
/h { closepath } bind def
/re { exch dup neg 3 1 roll 5 3 roll moveto 0 rlineto
      0 exch rlineto 0 rlineto closepath } bind def
/S { stroke } bind def
/f { fill } bind def
/f* { eofill } bind def
/n { newpath } bind def
/W { clip } bind def
/W* { eoclip } bind def
/BT { } bind def
/ET { } bind def
/pdfmark where { pop globaldict /?pdfmark /exec load put }
    { globaldict begin /?pdfmark /pop load def /pdfmark
    /cleartomark load def end } ifelse
/BDC { mark 3 1 roll /BDC pdfmark } bind def
/EMC { mark /EMC pdfmark } bind def
/cairo_store_point { /cairo_point_y exch def /cairo_point_x exch def } def
/Tj { show currentpoint cairo_store_point } bind def
/TJ {
  {
    dup
    type /stringtype eq
    { show } { -0.001 mul 0 cairo_font_matrix dtransform rmoveto } ifelse
  } forall
  currentpoint cairo_store_point
} bind def
/cairo_selectfont { cairo_font_matrix aload pop pop pop 0 0 6 array astore
    cairo_font exch selectfont cairo_point_x cairo_point_y moveto } bind def
/Tf { pop /cairo_font exch def /cairo_font_matrix where
      { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Td { matrix translate cairo_font_matrix matrix concatmatrix dup
      /cairo_font_matrix exch def dup 4 get exch 5 get cairo_store_point
      /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Tm { 2 copy 8 2 roll 6 array astore /cairo_font_matrix exch def
      cairo_store_point /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/g { setgray } bind def
/rg { setrgbcolor } bind def
/d1 { setcachedevice } bind def
/cairo_flush_ascii85_file { cairo_ascii85_file status { cairo_ascii85_file flushfile } if } def
/cairo_image { image cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
/cairo_imagemask { imagemask cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
%%EndSetup
%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginPageSetup
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 311 425
%%EndPageSetup
q 0 0 311 425 rectclip
1 0 0 -1 0 425 cm q
1 g
2.957 2.957 304.758 418.281 re f
0 g
5.915815 w
0 J
0 j
[] 0.0 d
4 M q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
2.957 2.957 304.758 418.281 re S Q
Q Q
showpage
%%Trailer
end restore
%%EOF
```

Comment: I just tried your `MWE` with `example-image-a` available in `graphicx` package and I see no problem. So my gut feeling is that, the image you are including is having a huge white-space instead.

Comment: Thank you for the lesson, graphicx:example-image-a, very useful.  However, my eps has a healthy bounding box and no whitespace.  Can hyperlink and eps working together have problems?

Comment: You are welcome, I just tried with one of my own `.eps` with tight bounding box. I still see no issue. Having said that I don't think `.eps` working with hyperlinks has a problem. May be if possible, could you provide your `.eps` file? Atleast, I dont know how to compile the script below your `MWE`.

Comment: Your comments led me straight to my current workaround: save all eps externally as pdf.  The above 2nd code block could be saved in a text editor as mwe1.eps.  But my current workaround, working with pdf's rather than eps's, is an acceptable solution, for which I am grateful to you, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What does your workflow for producing output-files (dvi/ps/pdf/whatever) from .tex-files look like?

I saved your postcript code as mwe1.eps.

**First I went the latex → dvips → ps2pdf-route:**

I compiled your MWE with latex and obtained a .dvi-file.
I run dvips on that .dvi-file and obtained a .ps-file.
I run ps2pdf on that .ps-file and obtained a .pdf-file.

That .pdf-file looks okay.

**Then I went the latex → dvipdf-route:**

I compiled your MWE with latex and obtained a .dvi-file.
I run dvipdf on that .dvi-file and obtained a .pdf-file.

That .pdf-file looks okay, too.

**Then I went the pdflatex-route:**

You cannot use .eps-files with pdflatex.
Thus I first called ps2pdf for converting mwe1.eps to mwe1.pdf.
The call on the command-line was: ps2pdf mwe1.eps .

When doing this, I got a file mwe1.pdf in A4-size where the nice little frame is somewhere in the bottom right corner. That's because on my system ps2pdf by default assumes that images will go on A4 pages.

Running pdfLaTeX on your MWE then of course yielded importing that .pdf-file whose measurements are too large. Thus the link was too large as well.

Then I realized what ps2pdf was doing and passed the -dEPSCrop-option when calling ps2pdf for converting mwe1.eps to mwe1.pdf:

ps2pdf -dEPSCrop mwe1.eps

This time I got mwe1.pdf not in A4-size but correctly cropped to the bounding-box specified in the header of mwe1.eps.

This time running pdfLaTeX on your MWE yielded a .pdf-file that looks okay and where the link is not too large.

By the way: My .log-file says about the TeX-Distribution used by me:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
```

I hope this helps.

(If I could produce comments with more characters, I would not have made an answer of this.)

Comment: exactly what I was trying now :D

Comment: @Raaja I only have problems when omitting the -dEPSCrop-option when converting mwe1.eps to mwe1.pdf.  That's why I asked the thread-initiator for info about the workflow for producing output.

Comment: Huhh, I understand :)

Comment: I used MikTex with XeLaTex.  But my original image(s) is/are anyway SVG format.  Whether I convert them to EPS or to PDF for inclusion into LaTex, is for my workflow equivalent.  Therefore, I remained with the solution of direct inclusion of externally produced PDF files.  Many thanks for your investigations and lessons.

Comment: pardon, not MikTex but TekWorks (Win10)